# CodeIgniter htaccess redirect url issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, url-rewriting

I want "nice urls" for my website. I'm looking at using `.htaccess` and I have tried many versions.

Now I have this:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
#  slashes.
# If your page resides at
#  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
# then use
# RewriteBase /mysite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
 # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

So this removes `index.php` from the URL. At first it was ok, but

Here is my `config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/mysite/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

And my .htaccess file is in my app root.
[folder img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iLN6.png)

I need a login for admin page, so `localhost/mysite/admin` is the my url for admin site.

```
public function index()
    {
    //  $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in'); session_destroy();
        $data['sitename']="Varkocs Old Pub";
         if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
           {
             $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
             $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
             $this->load->view('admin/home_view', $data);
       }
       else
       {
         //If no session, redirect to login page
         //redirect('login', 'refresh');


            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            $this->load->view('admin/login',$data);
       }

}
public function logout()
 {
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
   session_destroy();
   redirect('', 'refresh');
 }
```

This is my admin controller. I try here if logged in I load `home_view`, else the `login` view.

```
<div id="" class="container-fluid ">
    <div id="" class="row">
        <div id="" class="col-md-4 text-center admin_container">

          <h2><?php echo $sitename;?><h4>belépés az admin felületre</h4></h2>

           <?php  echo validation_errors('<p class="bg-danger">','</p>');?>

           <form action="verifylogin" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="username">Username:</label>
             <input class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="password">Password:</label>
             <input class="form-control" placeholder="password" type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
            </div>
             <input class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Login"/>
           </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the login view. I can't use here:

```
echo form_open('verifylogin');
```

Because it's returning the wrong URL.

So I write HTML:

```
<form action="verifylogin" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

The form validation with CodeIgniter is working. But the redirect afterwards doesn't work.

```
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
    $data['sitename']="Varkocs Old Pub";

     $this->load->view('admin/login',$data);

   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     redirect('admin', 'refresh');

     }
```

I have tried many ways to fix this, but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

The Codeigniter documentation says the following about the redirect function:

```
In order for this function to work it must be used before anything is outputted to the 
browser since it utilizes server headers.
```

This rule can be tricky to follow. A space or line end before the opening PHP tag will already break it.

Comment: my problem is with redirect. //Go to private area
     redirect('admin', 'refresh');

     }                                      http://localhost/mysite/localhost/mysite/admin              i set up the base url: localhost/mysite, i want to go localhost/mysite/admin controller. what can i do?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the redirect gave a blank page when you said it wasn't working. If it leads to the wrong page, you may need to adjust your base_url to an absolute url: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite/';`